# Save game data in png file

Tags: unity

I want to save my game as a PNG file. Which parts should I include in the file?

Should I include the alpha channel, EXIF data, or something else?

Comment: Maybe it would help to tell us why you want to do such a thing..?

Comment: I once had to encode binary data in images to demonstrate bypassing a firewall. If you use RGB24 or RGBA32, each channel can represent one byte per pixel and fairly cleanly. That said, you can use literally any format and encoding, so long as your reading/writing code adopt the same standard. I can't imagine why you'd want to do this in a game?

Comment: Do you want to save your data as stenography behind an original image, should the save file generate an image or what do you expect the png to represent? The parts you should include are the same as for any other save file: everything that is needed for your game to recreate the saved state, whatever that means for your game

Comment: @Basic Combining the PNG byte array and game data and saving the result as a PNG file is one way to achieve this.I’m wondering if there are any other better methods

Comment: Better methods _than what_ at achieving _what_?

Answer (score 0):

There is the code you can modify outPng as you wish (Texture2D have lot of useful methods) and then save it as png file anywhere you want:

```
Texture2D outPng;
var toPng = outPng.EncodeToPNG();
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/filename"+ ".png", toPng);
```

Comment: This is not answering the question in the regard on how to convert save data to the texture in the first place.